# What does it mean when a battery still has high voltage but doesn't deliver current?

Tags: multimeter, low-battery

All the dead batteries I tested had very small voltage and no current under load except one strange battery that had about 2 volts but no current. What causes this different type of dead battery? [image: no current]
[image: Still has voltage]

Answer (score 1):

The internal resistance of the battery is high? That would explain why the voltage is high when there is no current but why there is no voltage when there is current.

The more current is drawn by the battery, the more voltage is dropped across the internal resistance and therefore the less voltage actually appears on the battery terminals.

Comment: not really. I have 5 identical cr2016's that are dead. Only 1 has internal resistance?

Comment: What do you mean only one has internal resistance? That sentence doesn't make sense. You can't just measure the resistance across the battery with a meter since there is a voltage source inside too, along with a series resistor.

Comment: ie. why did only 4 show 0 volts and 1 show 2? Was this battery differently discharged?

Comment: @user5389726598465 Different levels of degradation and levels of charge?

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is the cell has a very high internal resistance, If a cell is dropped, the surface plate can delaminate from the positive terminal, which makes the ESR shoot up, you might see if fall if you squeeze it gently

I cannot tell from your image what the mode your using in the first image is, but that does not look like a battery load option, could you clarify exactly what mode you have it set to there?

Comment: I test the volts and then test the current under load to compare.

Comment: Maybe the issue is that 3 were in a car remote which draws very little current and kept functioning until they were really dead and the other stopped functioning in whatever it was in way before.

Comment: but what is that test under load function, what load, etc, are those units uA, mA etc, I'm afraid the image is not very clear

Comment: those are for 1.5v 4ma and 9v 25ma

Comment: the load is a constant 350 mWatts if I remember correctly from the manual.

Comment: So your load testing batteries by feeding 4mA from 1.5V, or 25mA from 9V, if that is the case, I would expect that you would need the 9V mode, and its not really testing the batteries under load, that seems more like an LED test mode